# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation & UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to implement auto-rotation in my application that is basically UINavigationController with lots of UIViewControllers that get pushed onto it.

I've copy-pasted this in my first UIViewController (that gets pushed into UINavigationController):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return YES;
}
```

Everything worked fine... However, if I paste in that code into second UIViewController (that first one pushes on top after some button click) - autorotation won't work. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called when UIViewController is first initialized, but after it is visible and I rotate device - nothing happens.

So result is: first view gets rotated well - portrait/landscape... but after I click button and get into second view I remain stuck into that portrait or landscape, whatever was active.

I tried subclassing UINavigationController and setting shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation there, but that also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see my response here as additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213885/ipad-orientation-change-issue/3239351#3239351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the API that doesn't cause it to work for the second view.  I solved it originally using setOrientation, but that's a private API and thus not a reasonable solution.  I haven't released any new versions of the application while I try to figure out alternatives (and I don't think having customers upgrade to OS 4.0 is a solution).  I'm thinking I'll need to manually keep track of the orientation and rotate my views manually to counteract the effects of the wrong rotation.

Comment: Please see my response here as additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213885/ipad-orientation-change-issue/3239351#3239351

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method in all views in the hierarchy

Comment: I said in question that I tried implementing it in all views (and that it only worked for first view).