# Set Orientation to Portrait on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, rotation, screen-orientation, autorotate

I have an application that consists of a login, 3 tables, and then an image.

You can rotate the image to landscape mode but what I want to be able to do is when the 'back' button is pushed and the app returns to the previous screen, I was the app to automatically rotate to give a portrait view.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You may want to heed this prior post too if you are getting strange issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213885/ipad-orientation-change-issue/3239351#3239351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the previous view controller only supports portrait (see `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`) then it should automatically rotate.

If the previous view controller supports landscape but you want it to rotate to portrait if it was originally in portrait, you can probably force it by changing what `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` returns when navigating back. I wouldn't recommend this; it's inconsistent UI (and it's a bit tedious to figure out what navigation is going on).

There are various ways to set the view controller interface orientation (`-[UIDevice setOrientation:]` will attempt to trigger an autorotation), but then you're into the realm of private APIs and potential rejection.

Answer (score 5):

For previous controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your table view controller and only return the orientation you want.

This might not actually switch back the orientation, so if this alone doesn't work you might have to call `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:` on `UIApplication` in your table view controller's `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` methods.