# shouldAutoRotate method not working properly..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have used multiple uiviewcontrollers in my split view based ipad application.
There are web services. For some particular web services  (e.g Logout) i need to remove split
view and insert new view i.e Login Screen. but most of times shouldAutoRotate method of Login view doesnt gets called resulting in dumb app which do not rotate.
        What may be the reason behind that? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have not extract a UIView from your UIViewController which shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: function return YES, and then add the UIView into another UIView use addSubView. I have encountered it before.

Comment: actually i gone thru following link, i found that i am doing mistake by adding 2 views in window. i.e loginview and splitview. now i have presented loginview as modal view which solved my problem. Now my app rotates well. Thakns.

Answer (score 1):

to maintain my legacy code I added this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) return YES;
    BOOL result = [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation];
    return result;
}
```

then the original code returns the valid autorotation information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your view controllers return `YES` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for your iPad build -- at least the ones that are visible at that time.

See: [iPad orientation change issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213885/ipad-orientation-change-issue/3239351)

Comment: ok thanks it helps me, I wl try.
Actually in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method i have calculated viewcontrollers size but in gives bad sizes i.e it provides prev orientation size instead current. So i have made some manual adjustment based on size. May it is affecting?